# How to send file with react and django rest

Tags: javascript, python, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

How can I send an image file from react to django.

I am new to react and  django , currently I am being successful in sending and getting data from/to the endpoints, now I want to send an image file or any other file from react to django or get image file from django to react.I wrote some code but its not working properly and i am facing quite difficulty to send file, I researched but not get any useful link.Kindly can someone share link from where I can get better understanding how it works.Here below is my try:

**REACT PART**

```
       let doc=new JsPDF();
       doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',30,30);
       //doc.save('test.pdf');
       let formdata=new FormData();
       formdata.append('file',doc);

       fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chauffeur/pdf_upload/`,
           {
               method: 'POST',
               body:formdata,
           }
       ).then(response => response.json()).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

**DJANGO PART**

```
class PdfUpload(APIView):

parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

def get(self, request):
    return Response([PdfSerializer(file).data for file in Pdf.objects.all()])

def post(self,request):
    payload=(request.data,request.FILES)
    print("Hello")
    print(payload)
    serializer=PdfSerializer(data=payload)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response("File Saved in Backend",status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

But I am getting too many errors from above code, like no file submitted or expected dict but receive list, can someone fix above code or can share helpful links from where I can understand better.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the name of object in your models.py is for example PdfModel write like this:

```
from django.core.files import File

def post(self, request):
    my_file = File(request.data.get('file'))
    new_pdf_file = PdfModel.objects.create(
         field1=request.data.get('field1'),
         field2=request.data.get('field2'), 
         field3=my_file )
    new_pdf_file.save()
    return Response({"something","something")
```